# How to save redux state between different URL routes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a react/redux webapp at www.infinity2o.com with multiple routes:

```
<Route exact={true} path="/profile" component={Profile} />
<Route exact={true} path="/sorting_hat" component={SortingHat} />
```

The problem I'm having is that my UI color theme is saved into my redux store. But every time my URL route changes like from `infinity2o.com/profile` to `infinity2o.com/sorting_hat` my entire state gets reset to `null`.

Is it possible to keep some of my redux state persistent when switching between routes?

Comment: You could also make it available through your service API, so that according to the URI, a specific theme would be returned and set into the state.

Comment: Normally navigating between routes(in a SPA like react) dosn't reset the state unless you refresh the app(F5), and we need to persist the state out of the store in case where our app is totally refreshed, but in your case (and you're using react-router) navigating to an other route shouldn't really reset your store, one other thing that could help you is using the ```LOCATION_CHANGE``` event from ```react-router-redux``` to detect the route change then you could handle the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try using redux-persist library

Answer (score 0):

You can save your state in **local storage** using **localStorage.setItem("key", "value")**. And set your initial redux state from local storage using **localStorage.getItem("key")**

Comment: Using local storage is [not a good idea](https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/).